# PrimeNg - unable to filter p-table with a parameter

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

Im using Angular 7 and PrimeNg library.

I have my p-table  delaration:

```
<p-table #tasktable [columns]="displayedColumns" [value]="Tasks" [globalFilterFields]="['name']" [paginator]="true" paginatorPosition="both"
     rows="20" [autoLayout]="true" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedTask"
     [reorderableColumns]="true" >
```

Then I have the text input for the global filter:

```
<input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Search by Task name" [(ngModel)]="filterFromUrl" (input)="tasktable.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto">
```

So far so good.
sometimes i get a parameter inside my URL, to get it 
I used in my component.ts:

```
 this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
 this.filterFromUrl = params['task'];
});
```

And now I have the parameter from the URL in my *filterFromUrl*  parameter.
My problem:

I cant get the table filter the data by the parameter.

I used [(ngModel)] bind in the   ,it doesn't work, 
I can see the parameter on the search control:
[image]

But it just doesn't fire the event and the data not filtered.

Comment: can you please demonsatrate your code on stackblitz for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the filters into the table (make sure it's in the format the table expects), like so:

```
@ViewChild("tasktable ") public table: Table;
this.table.filters = {global { value: 'SUBMIT_ORDER', matchMode: 'search' }};
```